# How do I revert back to iOS SDK 8 in XCode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl

Since the update to XCode 7 the iOS9 SDK was automatically installed. Because iOS9 prohibits non-SSL connections and my backend provider currently does not provide SSL for now, I cannot continue developing apps until SSL is available on my backend service (which can take a while). However, I noticed that if I install an older ad-hoc version of my app that I built a few weeks ago with XCode 6 and iOS SDK8, then iOS9 will allow non-SSL connections.

So, what I want to do is to revert back to iOS SDK8 in XCode 7 hoping that this will allow me to start non-SSL connections in iOS9 on my development device. Is this possible? If yes, how?

**Note:** I am aware that Apple does not allow non-SSL connections within apps for new app submissions to the app store. The intention of downgrading to iOS SDK8 is just temporarily for development purposes.

Comment: you cant!!! you have to go back to xcode 6

Comment: You can override this new behavior from App Transport Security by specifying the insecure domain in the Info.plist of your app.

Comment: @Mr.T That is incorrect, all that needs to be done is select the iOS8.x Deployment Target. But the real answer is to just whitelist the URL in the plist, see the  link in the answer by Rainer Schwarze.

Comment: Thanks for the info @zaph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Xcode preferences and go to "Downloads". Press the down arrow for the iOS Simulator for one of the 8.x versions.

[image]

For development purposes you can add ATS exceptions. This will be good enough for development. See here for more details: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31254725/1396265)

Comment: Great answer, danke Rainer! :)